# Javascript specs: promises chains and omitted expectations

Tags: javascript, testing, promise

Consider the following spec:

```
describe('User', () => {
  it('requires username', done => {
    factory.build('user', { username: '' })
      .then(user => user.validate())
      .catch(error => expect(error.errors.messages.username).toMatch('is required'))
      .then(done);
  });
});
```

In this case if the creation succeeds, then the `catch` callback is not invoked and we are `done`. So basically spec succeeds whereas it should fail.
This is just an example of a general problem: when we place expectation inside `then`/`catch` then we cannot be sure that they'll be called.

How would you write this?

For this concrete example I can think of such solution (but I don't like mixing callbacks with promises this way):

```
describe('User', () => {
  it('requires username', done => {
    factory.build('user', { username: '' })
      .then(user => user.validate(error =>
        expect(error.errors.messages.username).toMatch('is required')))
      .then(done);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would throw an error in the case that you don't expect:

```
return factory.build('user', { username: '' })
  .then(user => user.validate())
  .then(result => { throw new Error("expected rejection but got fulfilled promise"); },
        error => expect(error.errors.messages.username).toMatch('is required'))
```

Alternatively you can transform both cases into a result value on which you match, either manually or by using a promise method such as [`reflect`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/reflect.html):

```
  .then(result => null,
        error => error)
  .then(val => expect(val.errors.messages.username).toMatch('is required'))
```

If you know that the `result` is never an error-like object you can omit the first `onFulfilled` callback or just use `catch`.

Comment: I think it's kinda redundant, as we don't benefit from `except`. When the test fails we don't see something like `"expected null to match 'is required'"` but the exception message. Also doing this over and over seems cumbersome.

Comment: What do you mean by `except`? And if you're doing this over and over you can simply define a helper function that you pass to `then`, or use one of the many throwers that come with an assertion/testing library.

Comment: Ah I made a typo, I meant `expect`.